# ExpandableListView Position Changes

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView used as a Navigation Drawer. I also have a function, switchFragment. One of the parameters of switchFragment is the position. But, when I expand all groups and press an item, that item doesn't get highlighted. When I collapse a group, it does. How can I 'stable' that position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you "highlight" it but usually `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` does the trick.